# Unable to connect to redis db which is on machine-A and i am trying to connect to it from machine-b

Tags: express, server, redis

I am trying to run my express App in which i am using redis for my 
    session management. For this i am using two machines as my 
    servers(machine-a and machine-b). so my redis db I've configured 
   in machine-a and from that machine my app works fine. but when i am 
   enabling my machine-b there i am unable to connect to the redis db 
   which is in machine-a. i am unable to find how should i get 
   connected to redis db from machine-b.

I have tried giving IP addresses like 127.0.0.1, then port number 
   6379
   and then network IP address.

Below is the code, and the same code is written in machine-b too.

```
const express = require('express');
const session = require('express-session');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const redis = require('redis');
const redisStore = require('connect-redis')(session);
const client = redis.createClient();
const router = express.Router();
const app = express();

app.use(session({
    secret: 'ssshhhhh',
   // create new redis store.
   store: new redisStore({ host: 'localhost', port: 6379, client: 
          client, ttl: 260 }),
   saveUninitialized: false,
   resave: false
}));


app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('listen 3000');
    console.log(`App Started on PORT 3000}`);
});
```

I just want to get connected to the redis db which is in machine-a 
    form machine-b.

Comment: Is redis running on machine b too?

Comment: Do you configure firewall access roles for your Redis instance or port ?

Comment: @Astro No i am running redis only on machine-a and in maching-a i have nginx which is balancing machine-a and machin-b.

Comment: @MojtabaTajik i am not sure what you are asking ?

Comment: bind redis with private ip of the machine a and use that ip on machine b to connect with redis.

Comment: another way of making it work is disable protection using this command.

'redis-server --protected-mode no'

and then in the server.js file of the machine-b update the create client like this:

const client = redis.createClient({host:'machine-a ip', port:6379});